# Считывание из консоли за ограниченное время

Tags: java, многопоточность, консоль

Приветствую! Есть необходимость считать из консоли (а позже может быть и из GUI) данные в течение ограниченного времени. Появилась идея, но как я понимаю, такой способ, мягко говоря, небезопасен. Есть ли способы менее напоминающие велосипед на костылях?

```
static int number;

static void method(String args[]) {
  Thread thScan = new Thread(new Scan());
  thScan.start();
  try{ Thread.sleep(10000); } catch (Exception e) {}
  thScan.stop;
}

private static class Scan implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
    number = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да потоки не нужны.
На это вопрос уже есть ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input

```
public class test {

private String str = "";

TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
{
    public void run()
    {
        if( str.equals("") )
        {
            System.out.println( "you input nothing. exit..." );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }
    }    
};

public void getInput() throws Exception
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule( task, 10*1000 );

    System.out.println( "Input a string within 10 seconds: " );
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
    str = in.readLine();

    timer.cancel();
    System.out.println( "you have entered: "+ str ); 
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        (new test()).getInput();
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println( e );
    }
    System.out.println( "main exit..." );
}
}
```